# Как проверить является ли набор букв словом

Tags: python

На вход подаются строки по типу "эйсомош", "эндэди", "ложка". Как понять является ли строка осмысленным словом русского языка?

Comment: Проверка по словарю.

Comment: Никак, кроме как по словарю

Comment: тогда как сделать быструю проверку среди миллиона строк

Comment: Двоичный поиска в словаре из миллиона строк делается за двадцать операций если список отсортирован. И делается за одну операцию если список помещён в хеш-таблицу.

Comment: Дайте, пожалуйста, определение термина "слово русского языка"

Answer (score 3):

Можно и без словаря, через какой-нибудь лексический анализатор, но там не со всеми словами всё будет хорошо, с англицизмами и слэнгом будут проблемы, ну и порог надо подбирать:

```py
# !pip install pymorphy2[fast]
import pymorphy2

lst = ["эйсомош", "эндэди", "ложка", "спрайт", "Владимир", "ололо", "лол", "няка", "няня", "принтер", "козявка", "козябра"]
threshold = 0.75

morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
for word in lst:
    p = morph.parse(word)
    score = p[0].score
    print(f'{word} - {"осмысленное" if score >= threshold else "бред"}')
```

Вывод:

```
эйсомош - бред
эндэди - бред
ложка - осмысленное
спрайт - бред
Владимир - осмысленное
ололо - осмысленное
лол - бред
няка - бред
няня - осмысленное
принтер - бред
козявка - осмысленное
козябра - бред
```

Зато у анализатора хорошо со склонениями и т.п., они ему не сильно мешают, а вот словарь обычно только именительный падеж единственное число понимает.

Comment: А существует ли аналог pymorphy2 для английского языка? Интересует именно как раз оно самое - является ли набор букв - словом? Я искал, но вроде не нашел.

Comment: @Gh0sTG0 Конечно, этим занимается NLTK https://www.nltk.org/ только у него гораздо шире функции.

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы распознать именно слова из "нечего" такое навряд ли возможно, но можно установить правила их составления, но тогда "специфические" слова будут не распознаваться
Самая лучшая методика для этого поиск по словарю, так как тут никак не ошибёшся:

```
listing = []
word = input("Введите слово: ")
if word.upper() in listing:
    print("Данное слово присуствует в словаре")
else:
    print("Незнаю такого слова, хотите добавить в словарь? (Да или нет)")
    if input().upper() == "ДА":
        listing.append(input("Введите слово"))
```

Можно заморочиться и поискать правила насчёт слов и сделать регулярное выражение которое будет вычислять некоторые слов, но это достаточно сложно и может заносить даже бред кроме слов.

Comment: *"и сделать регулярное выражение"* - мсье знает толк в извращениях )